# confusing with mysql Nested Select Query using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

please help to find what the mistake here. Actually i am a beginner.. Help Me..

```
$query1="select Sub_Code,Sub_Name from subj_mast where Dept_id='(select Dep_Id from academic where Reg_No=$reg)' and Sem='$sem'";
```

The above query is not working but when i split like this its working...

```
$query2="select Dep_Id from academic where Reg_No=$reg";
$query3="select Sub_Code,Sub_Name from subj_mast where Dept_id='104' and Sem='$sem'";
```

here 104 is Dept_id corresponds to Reg_No given. 104 is got by using query2.
Confused a lot ... is my query1 is right???

Comment: I hope you have used [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because this looks terrifyingly insecure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrapping your subquery inside of quotes. Remove the quotes.

Eg:

```
$query1="select Sub_Code,Sub_Name from subj_mast where Dept_id=(select Dep_Id from academic where Reg_No=$reg) and Sem='$sem'";
```